# what 's the difference between 2 gradle dependencies

Tags: dependencies, build.gradle

What 's the difference between

```
compile group: 'org.springframework.data',
name: 'spring-data-jpa',
version: '1.11.6.RELEASE'
```

and

```
compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
```

regardless of the `version ('1.11.6.RELEASE')`?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remote dependencies in Gradle are structured as follows:

```
compile 'group:name:version'
```

or this alternative syntax:

```
compile group: 'xxx', name: 'xxxxx', version: 'xxxx'
```

Then you can use:

```
dependencies { 
    compile "org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:1.11.6.RELEASE" 
}
```

or

```
dependencies { 
    compile group: 'org.springframework.data', name: 'spring-data-jpa', version: '1.11.6.RELEASE'
}
```